# Python comes up with an error in the end the error says KeyError 'Open'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to extract stock prices from the website 'iex' and everything works fine until I try to plot my data into a visualization model. Can anyone take a look and see what I am doing wrong? This happens when I put the coding for 'open' as well as 'volume' Thank you!

```
msft['Open'].plot(label='MSFT',figsize=(16,8),title='Open Title')
gm['Open'].plot(label='gm')
ford['Open'].plot(label='ford')plt.legend()
```

I get the follow error

```
KeyError: 'Open'
```

[image: This is the Error I receive when coding]

Comment: msft doesn't have a column named Open.

Comment: hey there thanks for the response. Still new here, what do you mean by a column named open? Do I need to write a new set that is open for msft? I first set up my code as start=datetime.date(2014,1,1) end = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1) and then put in msft = web.DataReader('MSFT', 'iex', start, end) and then msft.head to get a chart of the stock prices that were opened and closed starting from 2014 @AndyHayden

Comment: What do you expect `msft['Open']` to do?

Comment: I was trying to get the opening price when running the line 'start=datetime.date(2014,1,1) end = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1) msft = web.DataReader('MSFT', 'iex', start, end)' therfore I can have this charted as a linear plot @AndyHayden

Answer (score 0):

pandas datareader uses lower case `"open"`:

```
In [11]: from pandas_datareader import data as web

In [12]: msft = web.DataReader('MSFT', 'iex', "2019-01-01", "2019-01-31")

In [13]: msft.head()
Out[13]:
                open      high       low     close    volume
date
2019-01-02   99.1266  101.3173   98.5192  100.6899  35329345
2019-01-03   99.6743   99.7589   96.7866   96.9858  42578410
2019-01-04   99.2959  102.0740   98.5093  101.4965  44060620
2019-01-07  101.2077  102.8289  100.5505  101.6259  35656136
2019-01-08  102.6018  103.5278  101.2808  102.3628  31514415

In [14]: msft["open"].head()
Out[14]:
date
2019-01-02     99.1266
2019-01-03     99.6743
2019-01-04     99.2959
2019-01-07    101.2077
2019-01-08    102.6018
Name: open, dtype: float64
```